# Converting to swift 4 : Build input file cannot be found target:Tests/_5__2Tests.swift'

Tags: xcode, target, xcode10

I have a project that I'm working on which runs perfectly in the simulator (in Xcode 10.1) but when I try to convert my project from swift 3 to swift 4.2  I get this error in my test targets.

Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/....... #2UITests/_5__2UITests.swift'

and Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/Roberto/Downloads.... #2UITests/Info.plist'

I have read several blogs about going into your test target removing the Plist and re adding the plist but if I remove it and re add it I get

:-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/roberto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/25_#2-edsolzqlcfejkgcvjolfrdmxdmon/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SwiftMigration/25 #2/Products/Debug-iphoneos/25 #2UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/25 #2UITests.xctest/Info.plist':
1) Target '25 #2UITests' (project '25 #2') has copy command from '/Users/... #2UITests/Info.plist'

Comment: I would just remove the test target entirely.

Comment: @matt that actually worked.... I don't know why I didn't think of that and just tried to make it work. When I originally created the project a year ago it already had the test targets in there so I just left them

Comment: Cool, I'll give it as an answer, as this might help others.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just removing the test target entirely. If you actually have tests, it's no loss because deleting the target doesn't delete the files.